# get index of matched element between two array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array of objects. I want to get the index of matched element from array 2. How to find that?

This is an example.

**Array 1**

```
selectedProduct: [{id:2, name:"product 1", category:"home"}]
```

**Array 2**

```
allProducts: [{id:1, name:"product 3", category:"grocery"},
             {id:2, name:"product 1", category:"home"},{id:3, name:"product 4",category:"vegetables"}]
```

**Code snippet:**

```
const index = this.allProducts.findIndex(item => this.selectedproduct.filter(entry => entry.id === item.id))
```

But, it is returning 0. How can i get the index of matched element?

Comment: Change [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: @user7411584 please mark the answer as the solution if it solved the problem so future visitors can benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `some` instead:

```js
let selectedProduct = [
  {id:2, name:"product 1", category:"home"}
];
let allProducts = [
  {id:1, name:"product 3", category:"grocery"},
  {id:2, name:"product 1", category:"home"},
  {id:3, name:"product 4",category:"vegetables"}
]

const index = allProducts.findIndex(item => selectedProduct.some(entry => entry.id === item.id));

console.log(index);
```

Comment: While this does technically work, that's not the purpose of `find`, which returns the first matching element or `undefined`. `some` is more appropriate since it returns a boolean `true` even if the element found is falsy.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks for the comment. Yes ``some`` is better for this case.